# How to get viewForZoomingInScrollView to work across multiple UIViewControllers in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode8

I'm relatively new to Xcode, and am in the process of making an app in Objective C with several viewControllers each with a single UIScrollView containing a single UIImage that can be zoomed and scrolled.

This code works for the first image (dermatomes), but I can't figure out how to tweak the UIView to enable zooming and scrolling on the second image (anatomicPlanes). Currently the second image imports correctly to the second UIScrollView, but when I try to zoom it just jumps down and right and remains static there.

The size of the UIScrollViews were set using Interface Builder, no problems there.

viewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *dermatomeScrollView;
    UIImageView *dermatomesImageView;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *anatomicPlaneScrollView;
    UIImageView *anatomicPlanesImageView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *dermatomeScrollView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dermatomesImageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *anatomicPlanesImageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *anatomicPlaneScrollView;

@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize dermatomeScrollView, anatomicPlanesImageView, dermatomesImageView, anatomicPlaneScrollView;

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return dermatomesImageView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *dermatomes = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                  initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dermatomes.jpg"]];

    self.dermatomesImageView = dermatomes;
    dermatomeScrollView. maximumZoomScale = 1.2;
    dermatomeScrollView. minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
    dermatomeScrollView. delegate = self;
    [dermatomeScrollView addSubview:dermatomesImageView];
    dermatomeScrollView.zoomScale = 0.6;

    UIImageView *planes = [[UIImageView alloc]
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anatomic planes.jpg"]];
    self.anatomicPlanesImageView = planes;
    anatomicPlaneScrollView. maximumZoomScale = 1.2;
    anatomicPlaneScrollView. minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
    anatomicPlaneScrollView. delegate = self;
    [anatomicPlaneScrollView addSubview:anatomicPlanesImageView];
    anatomicPlaneScrollView.zoomScale = 0.6;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the correct view based on the scroll view that is requesting. Every method in the delegate pattern is passed a reference to the originator of the method call, so your delegate implementation can handle it differently. In this case, the originator of the delegate method call is the scroll view:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == dermatomeScrollView) {
        return dermatomesImageView;
    }

    return anatomicPlanesImageView;
}
```

If you add more scrollviews, you'll have to extend this method further.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for (intuitive now that I see it, but it didn't occur to me).

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you! Don't forget to accept my answer. :)

Comment: Done. And in case anyone else runs into this issue, to prevent a "control may reach end of non-void function" error, add an else { return nil;} clause

Comment: I'm not sure where you would have seen that error message, because both code paths in the snippet I posted ended in a `return`. (For anyone who may be confused by your comment. )